# How to send multiple images to cloudinary?

Tags: c#, cloudinary

Follow code:

```
string[] files 
      = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Pictures", "*.jpg");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
    {
        File = new FileDescription(file),
        PublicId = "my_folder/images",
        EagerAsync = true
    };

    var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
}
```

It is not working, it is always recording the previous file.

I'm trying to save multiple images to cloudinary and nothing is success.

Only one image is saved. I use a libray [Cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/dotnet_image_upload).

Any solution ?

Comment: `it is always recording the previous file.` What does that mean?

Comment: @mjwills is not adding the image, just overwriting the previous image. It's like an update.

Comment: What is the value of `uploadResult.Url` for the first file? The second file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I tested it out, it works as expected; however, I would adjust a couple of things. The first thing is that you do not need the parameter `eager_async` as no `eager` transformation is being applied to the assets. An eager transformation lets you create a modified version of the original asynchronously after the asset has been uploaded. Secondly, if you wish to see the upload response, you can use property JsonObj and display it in the console. I have modified your sample here:

```
string[] files
= System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Pictures", "*.jpg");

foreach (var file in files)
{
    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
    {
        File = new FileDescription(file),
        UseFilename = true
    };

    var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
    Console.WriteLine(uploadResult.JsonObj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

```
string[] files = 
    System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Matheus Miranda\Pictures\teste", "*.jpg");

for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
{
    var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
    {
        File = new FileDescription(files[i]),
        PublicId = $"my_folder/images/{System.IO.Path.GetFileName(files[i])}"
    };
    var uploadResult = cloudinary.Upload(uploadParams);
}
```